# send bitmap image from class to form

Tags: c#, forms, class, picturebox

The title should explain it all really, I have a method in a class file that is currently being executed and it loads and image and stores it in a bitmap variable. My aim is to display this image to the user, so i also have a form class with a picture box. How can I load this form from a separate class, sending the form the image to store in the picture box?

class

```
public void execute()
{
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(location);
    //add call form code here
}
```

form

```
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        //perhaps add image to picture box here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This managed to solve it,

```
     public void execute()
     {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(location);
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.BackgroundImage = img;
        f.Show();
     }
```

For some reason it wouldn't work with the picturebox but it does with the background and thats sufficient for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Image` property of the `PictureBox` with the result that you get from your class

```
myPictureBox.Image = (Image)MyClass.GetBitmap();
```

Comment: `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is a child class of `System.Drawing.Image`, so you don't have to cast it.
[MSDN Source (Bitmap Class)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I dont think that will work as i still need to initialize the form from the class method

Answer (score 1):

In your form class add a public property for an image.

```cs
public Image PictureBoxImage   
{   
    set
    {
        this.pictureBox.Image = value;
    }
}
```

Moving on to your other class these are the steps for opening a form:

1. Create the form object `CustomForm form1 = new CustomeForm;`
2. In your case you need to change the picture by setting the property that you just added
   `form1.PictureBoxImage = (Image)yourBitmap;`
3. Finally you need to display it to the user `form1.Show();`